# How to remove cookies related to username and password when click LogOff link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, code-first

**Problem**

**when click logoff link cookies not removed from my browser(internet explorer and google chrome) .**

I working in visual studio 2015 with asp.net mvc 4

**what i try**

**I cannot remove cookies if username and password exist before(problem found in this point)** .

```
 public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("LogOff", "Account");
        }
```

for login view get
I can restore username and password in login if username and password logged before(no problem in that)

```
public ActionResult Login()
        {
            UserAccount model = new UserAccount();
            if (Request.Cookies["Login"] != null)
            {
                 model.UserName = Request.Cookies["Login"].Values["UserName"];
                 model.Password = Request.Cookies["Login"].Values["Password"];
            }
            return View(model);
```

From my code below i can login if username and password is correct
also i can save username and password in cookies(no problem in that) .

```
public ActionResult Login(UserAccount user)
        {
            using (ContainerClass db = new ContainerClass())
            {
                var usr = db.userAccount.Where(u => u.UserName == user.UserName && u.Password == user.Password).FirstOrDefault();

                if (usr != null)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, user.RememberMe);
                    Session["UserID"] = user.UserID.ToString();
                    Session["UserName"] = user.UserName.ToString();

                    if (user.RememberMe)
                    {
                        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Login");
                        cookie.Values.Add("UserID", user.UserID.ToString());
                        cookie.Values.Add("UserName", user.UserName);
                        cookie.Values.Add("Password", user.Password);
                        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15);
                        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                    }

                      return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn", "Account");

                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or Password is wrong");
                }

            }

            return View(user);
        }
```

Comment: not related to the issue. but you don't have to save the username and pass in cookie.. its not good practice.. If the user has not logged out you can check it in `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

Comment: can you tell me how to change cookies to  User.Identity.IsAuthenticated if possible

Comment: Since you are using Forms authentication it's available by default.. just check once in your controller